# How do I delete a file referenced inside a document before this documet is deleted using mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, hook

I have a collection of documents in mongodb, every document of that collections tracks a file on the server, I want delete a files when its corresponding document is deleted. ¿How can I do that?, the documents will be massively delete using a query.

I have the following model:

```
const AudioSchema = new Schema({
 file: String,
 title: String,
 user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
})
mongoose.model('Audio', AudioSchema)
```

As you can see, every document keep a track of a **file** existing in the file system in the server, it happens I want to delete that file in the case the document is deleted. Usually the way this documents will be removed is via a Model Query, (Is not an option using a document hook, just model hooks) example:

```
const result = await Audio.deleteOne({
  _id: audioannotation_id,}).exec()
```

I know that if the document was deleted by document, I could use a "***pree***" hook like this

```
AudioSchema.pre('deleteOne',{ query: false , document : true}, function(){
  fs.unlink(this.file, err => { throw err})
})
```

But as I mentioned earlier, is mandatory not to use document hooks, because these types of documents will be massively deleted by using model queryes.

If I use a Model Hook, I'm not able to know what document will be deleted, because **this* is not working as a reference to the document that will be deleted.

```
Audio.pre('deleteOne',{ query: true , document : false}, function(){
  this.file // In this case **this** is not referencing the current document to be deleted
})
```

Any sugestion?

Comment: can you explain what's the problem of pre hook in deleteOne?

Comment: The documents will be deleted in bulk using a query, so in this case the document hook won't fire.